# I get the error: too much recursion. Why is that?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to refresh graphs on a page. The idea is that it loops constantly and refreshes a variable called `salt`. Variables are defined in a separate file and are called `path`, `displayTimeFrom`, `selectedTimeRangeType` and `target`. Here is the looping code which also responds to changes in the GUI:

```
$(function () {
    refreshGraphs();
});

var refreshGraphs = function () {
    d = new Date();

    var graphiteUrl = graphs.path + "render/?_salt" + d.getTime()
                + "&from=-" + graphs.displayTimeFrom
                + graphs.selectedTimeRangeType
                + "&minXStep=0"
                + "&until=now&height=800&";

    $('#graph-middle').prop("src", graphiteUrl + graphs.target);

    setIntervalAndExecute(refreshGraphs, 30000); // refresh every 30000 milliseconds aka every 30 seconds

    // Execute immediately and after the interval (setInterval only starts after certain amount of time)
    function setIntervalAndExecute(fn, t) {
        fn();
        return (setInterval(fn, t));
    }

    // Change graph to chosen value
    $('#graph-middle').on('click', '#displayTimeFrom', function () {
        graphs.displayTimeFrom = $(this).text();
        refreshGraphs();
    });

    $('#graph-middle').on('click', '#selectedTimeRangeType', function () {
        graphs.selectedTimeRangeType = $(this).text();
        refreshGraphs();
    });
};
```

When I run it it says `"too much recursion"`. Why is that and how can I solve it?

Comment: I have edited my answer. please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to note:
1. You're invoking `refreshGraphs()` recursively.
2. You have placed `click` handlers in the `refreshGraphs()` function.

So whenever this `refreshGraphs()` are invoked it is binding the `click` events again without unbinding the previous one. You have to either unbind the previous one or you can place them in `$(function () {})`.

Try any of these.

```
$(function () {
    refreshGraphs();
    // Change graph to chosen value
    $('#graph-middle').on('click', '#displayTimeFrom', function () {
        graphs.displayTimeFrom = $(this).text();
        refreshGraphs();
    });

    $('#graph-middle').on('click', '#selectedTimeRangeType', function () {
        graphs.selectedTimeRangeType = $(this).text();
        refreshGraphs();
    });
});

var refreshGraphs = function () {
    d = new Date();

    var graphiteUrl = graphs.path + "render/?_salt" + d.getTime()
                + "&from=-" + graphs.displayTimeFrom
                + graphs.selectedTimeRangeType
                + "&minXStep=0"
                + "&until=now&height=800&";

    $('#graph-middle').prop("src", graphiteUrl + graphs.target);

    setIntervalAndExecute(refreshGraphs, 30000); // refresh every 30000 milliseconds aka every 30 seconds

    // Execute immediately and after the interval (setInterval only starts after certain amount of time)
    function setIntervalAndExecute(fn, t) {
        fn();
        return (setInterval(fn, t));
    }
};
```

Or

```
$(function () {
    refreshGraphs();
});

var refreshGraphs = function () {
    d = new Date();

    var graphiteUrl = graphs.path + "render/?_salt" + d.getTime()
                + "&from=-" + graphs.displayTimeFrom
                + graphs.selectedTimeRangeType
                + "&minXStep=0"
                + "&until=now&height=800&";

    $('#graph-middle').prop("src", graphiteUrl + graphs.target);

    setIntervalAndExecute(refreshGraphs, 30000); // refresh every 30000 milliseconds aka every 30 seconds

    // Execute immediately and after the interval (setInterval only starts after certain amount of time)
    function setIntervalAndExecute(fn, t) {
        fn();
        return (setInterval(fn, t));
    }

    // Change graph to chosen value
    $('#graph-middle').off('click').on('click', '#displayTimeFrom', function () {
        graphs.displayTimeFrom = $(this).text();
        refreshGraphs();
    });

    $('#graph-middle').off('click').on('click', '#selectedTimeRangeType', function () {
        graphs.selectedTimeRangeType = $(this).text();
        refreshGraphs();
    });
};
```

Comment: It's best to explain what you changed and why you changed it, rather than leaving OP wondering.

Answer (score 4):

Your `refreshGraphs()` function calls itself immediately (via `setIntervalAndExecute()`) every time it runs.

Comment: That is not the problem. This recursion is allowed since there is a wait of 30 seconds. The problem was the jQuery binding in the refreshgraphs function. Once I placed those in the anonymous function on top (document ready), things were fine.

Comment: @user2609980: No; the `fn()` call runs it immediately too.

Comment: Well, it is not a problem when I place the jQuery code in the `$(function()`.

Comment: I am looking at the code again. And I see now that you must be right. By moving the `setIntervalAndExecute` to the `$function()` and outside of `refreshGraphs` I think I have made sure that the immediate and recursive execution of `fn()` is called only once (no access to the code now so not sure what the solution exactly was). I will take a look later. The code runs perfectly fine for months on end though (i.e., it refreshes the graphs every 30 seconds...). I am wondering if the jQuery calls to `refreshGraphs()` make some sort of intricate loop that just works.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to call the jQuery in the anonymous function instead of the refreshGraps namespace. Issue solved.